# setuptools is including dist/ folder in build

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

i am using setuptools to create and upload a sdist package to PyPI.

however everytime i run python setup.py sdist, it includes the dist/ folder and its contents, which i dont want . this behavoir does NOT happen when i use distutils.

here is my file structure:

```
/
-myModule/
--__init_.py,
-- ...
-docs/
-examples/
-dist/
setup.py
```

this is also my svn trunk root. here is my setup.py

```
import ez_setup
ez_setup.use_setuptools()

from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(name='mymodule',
    version='1.0',
    license='gpl',
    description='blahn',
    author='me',
    author_email='myemail',
    url='http://code.google.com/p/mymodule/',
    packages= find_packages(),
    install_requires = [
        'numpy>=1.3.0',
        'scipy>=0.7.1',
        'matplotlib>=1.0.0'
        ],
    )
```

when see this output, which indicates the problem

```
python setup.py sdist
...
making hard links in mwavepy-1.0...
hard linking MANIFEST.in -> mwavepy-1.0
hard linking ez_setup.py -> mwavepy-1.0
hard linking setup.py -> mwavepy-1.0
hard linking dist/mwavepy-1.0.tar.gz -> mwavepy-1.0/dist
hard linking dist/mwavepy-1.0.win32.exe -> mwavepy-1.0/dist
hard linking dist/mwavepy-1.0.zip -> mwavepy-1.0/dist
hard linking doc/generate_docs.py -> mwavepy-1.0/doc
hard linking doc/mwavepy.calibration.html -> mwavepy-1.0/doc
hard linking doc/mwavepy.calibrationAlgorithms.html -> mwavep
...
```

Comment: You need to show us the relevant parts of setup.py - the sdist command normally doesn't do that. Maybe you specified "dist" in `data_files` or so?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem (I don't have the `ez_setup` module, maybe that makes a difference?). What's your setuptools version? Check with `setuptools.__version__`.

Comment: using setup form setuputils instead of ez_setup, doesnt* change.i am using setuptools-0.6. using distutils does not have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `find_packages()` statement and replace it with

```
setup(
    ...
    packages = ['myModule'],
    package_dir = {'myModule' : 'myModule_path'},
    ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could alternatively pass an argument to `find_packages()`:

```
setup(
    #...
    packages= find_packages(exclude='dist'),
    # ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened for me, until I ran `svn rm dist/foo.tar.gz`, and then it wasn't hard-linked anymore, and wasn't in the resulting tarball. The documentation for [setuptools](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) does mention different behavior based on whether a file is under CVS or SVN control:

> include_package_data
>
> If set to True, this tells setuptools to automatically include any
>   data files it finds inside your package directories, that are either
>   under CVS or Subversion control, or which are specified by your
>   MANIFEST.in file.